# Single add to basket in Exp:resso Store?

Tags: add-on, expresso-store

I'm using Exp:resso store, everything is working fine, but I have multiple "Add to Cart" buttons on the page, one for every product.  Is there anyway to have just one Single Add to Cart at the bottom of the form?

As an example, my products page currently has 50+ items listed, each with there own Add to Cart button beside it.  I'd like the customer to be able to go down through the list, entering  the totals as they go, then clicking on an one Add to Cart button of the bottom of the list to update the cart.

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is referred to (at least by Store) as "multi add to cart".

You should take a look at the [Product Form Tag](https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/product_form_tag.html). From the docs:

> The product form tag is used to create custom add to cart forms, which allow the customer to add multiple items to their cart at once. Most websites will not need to use this tag, as the Product Tag already provides an add to cart form wrapped around a single product.

Really simple example:

```
{exp:store:product_form}
  {exp:channel:entries channel="products" dynamic="no" limit="5"}
      {exp:store:product disable_form="yes" entry_id="{entry_id}"}
          <!-- add to cart form / product details -->
    {exp:store:product}
  {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:store:product_form}
```